# Identifier name is too long zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am writing a SQL query using *Zend Framework 2* database abstraction layer, involving a subquery with join but it results in the following error:

```
Statement could not be executed (42000 - 1059 - Identifier name '(select article_id a,GROUP_CONCAT(reference_data SEPARATOR '#') r from article_ref_data GROUP BY a)' is too long)
```

**My code so far:**

```php
$ref_data = "(select article_id a,GROUP_CONCAT(reference_data SEPARATOR '#') r from article_ref_data GROUP BY a)";
$adapter = new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter ( $db );
$sql = new Sql ( $adapter );

$select = $sql->select ()->columns (array('article_id', 'article_doi','title', 'first_page', 'last_page', 'pages',
      'print_publish_date'=>new Expression('DATE_FORMAT (print_publish_date, \'%d-%m-%Y\')'),
      'online_publish_date'=>new Expression('DATE_FORMAT (online_publish_date, \'%d-%m-%Y\')'),
      'received_date'=>new Expression('DATE_FORMAT (received_date, \'%d-%m-%Y\')'),
      'accepted_date'=>new Expression('DATE_FORMAT (accepted_date, \'%d-%m-%Y\')'),
      'total_view'));
$select->from ( array ('a'      => 'article') );
$select->join ( array ('j'      => 'journal'),'j.journal_id = a.journal_id',array ('journal_code'), 'left' );
$select->join ( array ('v'      => 'volume'),'v.volume_id = a.volume_id', array ('volume_no'), 'left' );
$select->join ( array ('i'      => 'issue'), 'i.issue_id = a.issue_id', array ('number', 'issue_title'), 'left' );
$select->join ( array ('rat'    => 'ref_article_type'),'rat.article_type_id = a.article_type_id',   array ('article_type'), 'left' );
$select->join ( array ('ras'    => 'ref_article_status'),'ras.article_status_id = a.article_status_id', array ('article_status_name'), 'left' );
$select->join ( array ('ref_at' => 'ref_access_type'),'ref_at.access_type_id = a.access_type_id',   array ('access_type'), 'left' );
$select->join ( array ('ref_lt' => 'ref_license_type'), 'ref_lt.license_type_id = a.license_type_id',   array ('license_type'), 'left' );
$select->join (array ('ard' => $ref_data), 'ard.article_id = a.article_id', array ('ref'), 'left' );
$select->where ( array ('a.journal_id = ?' => $journal_id) );       

$statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject ( $select );        
$sql_result = $statement->execute ();
$results = new ResultSet ();
$results = $results->initialize ( $sql_result )->toArray ();
return $results;
```

Comment: The ref data join begins with "(select ?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your query as string and not as `Select` object, therefore Zend interprets it as the table name, and not as subquery

```php
$select->join(['ard' => 'SUB_TABLE'], 'join_conditions',['COLUMN_I_WANT']);
```

becomes

```sql
select ard.COLUMN_I_WANT
from ...
JOIN SUB_TABLE AS ard WHERE join_conditions
```

If you take a look on the generated SQL query (`$select->getSqlString($adapter->getPlatform()`), you'll get:

```sql
SELECT `a`.`article_id`    AS `article_id`, 
       `ard`.`ref`         AS `ref` 
FROM   `article` AS `a` 
LEFT JOIN `(select article_id a,group_concat(reference_data separator '#') r from article_ref_data group by a)` 
    AS `ard` 
    ON `ard`.`article_id` = `a`.`article_id`
```

As you can see, the query is not interpreted as "query", but just as a name.

If you write it as subquery:

```php
$adapter = new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter($db);
$sql = new Sql($adapter);

$ref_data = $sql->select()
        ->columns([
            'article_id' => 'article_id',
            'ref' => new Expression("GROUP_CONCAT (reference_data SEPARATOR '#')")
        ])
        ->from('article_ref_data')
        ->group('a');

// You don't need to change anything else, $select is perfect the way it is
```

Will give you this SQL query:

```sql
SELECT `a`.`article_id`     AS `article_id`,
       `ard`.`ref`          AS `ref` 
FROM   `article` AS `a`
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT `article_ref_data`.`article_id`             AS `article_id`, 
           Group_concat (reference_data SEPARATOR '#') AS `ref` 
    FROM   `article_ref_data` 
    GROUP  BY `a`
) AS `ard` ON `ard`.`article_id` = `a`.`article_id`
```

### Pay attention

Inside subquery, you two aliases as `a` and `r`, but then in the main select you reference the fields as `article_id` and `ref`.

I already fixed this in the proposed solution ;)